# Will cut and pasting from pdf to sublime text generate dirty code?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I'm studying css/html via a pdf workbook, and I'm wondering if it's ok to cut and paste code from this into my text editor (Sublime Text) or will this result in "dirty code"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"dirty"*? Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: What you see is what you get in the editor. Editors are plain-text. These are not rich text editors that copy colors, bolded text etc. The syntax highlighting will be applied depending on the code editor and theme. Shortly - yes. You can copy paste. Generally I would recommend you to re-write the code, you will learn better :)

Comment: @ Jonsharpe...please see the comment I left for LiamOnRails...I've since discovered that it was a book error. I tried cut and pasting different code from the book into Sublime and it worked fine...Also by dirty code I'm referring to the code that's been copied from say a Microsoft Word Doc and pasted into Sublime. The code can have the correct syntax, but won't work as expected to...it's as if something has been lost in translation. My partner's a Graphic Design Lecturer and said the same thing happens if you  paste text from a Word Doc into Publisher, Publisher doesn't know what to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have 'dirty' code in the sense that you would if you pasted something into an editor that has a design view and was **generating** code. Sublime Text is only a text/code editor.

However, when cutting and pasting from PDFs you have to be especially careful about line breaks, columns, dashes at the end of lines etc. Especially true if your language cares about line breaks and indentations. (HTML/CSS is far more forgiving that others.)

But, you should be fine. Just pay attention to what the code looks like when you paste it, and clean up a bit if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It won't produce dirty code no.

If you are studying HTML and CSS or in fact any sort of code I would always suggest to type it out manually to help your brain absorb the information much easier... So, no it won't but my advice is to type it all out manually.

Comment: Yes normally I do type code out manually but because I couldn't get the code to work I thought why not just copy and paste it from the book...however after doing so the code still didn't work and so I figured a) it's an error in the book or b) copying and pasting doesn't work...I've been told you can run into problems if you copy and paste from a Word doc into Notepad ++, so I thought maybe Sublime Text was precious too...

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the other answer here, you have to pay attention to line breaks etc. Just as a general piece of advice, if you type code and it doesn't work and so you give up and copy paste code from somewhere else, you will only get so far. Part of being good at web development is attention to detail and working your way through errors, get in the mindset of seeing errors as a wall to jump over, it will set you in the right direction.